# Is it possible to activate a tab from drawer using javascript in Material Design Light?

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

Is it possible to activate a tab using javascript in Material Design Lite?

I want to activate a tab using the links inside `mdl-layout__drawer`?

Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently toggling tabs programatically isn't supported.

You would need to reverse how tabs are toggled and implement your own function to handle the same logic.

Comment: reverse engineering can fail later if the implementation changes, resulting in code that can be brittle and harder to maintain.   By simulating a "click" on the tab, you don't need to know what's going on behind the scenes.  See my answer below.

Comment: We aren't changing the implementation internally, because BC concerns just like this. Material Components for Web will have a tab system built to support pragmatic manipulation.

Comment: You're right.  The internals aren't being changed, they are being abandoned in favor of a rewrite and name change.   Hopefully "Material Components for Web" won't be as bloated and difficult as polymer, but my point still stands.  Don't rely on a crystal ball and reverse engineer code when easier solutions exist that don't require studying someone else's code which is always subject to change.

Answer (score 1):

No problem.  I assume you want everything in the drawer to mirror your tabs.  If you want to only have certain items activate tabs and not all, just adjust the last line in the sample code, maybe add a "drawer-tab-clicker" class if you want to single out which links activate tabs and which don't.  I wanted them all, so the sample below does all the drawer links.

You should give your drawer links the same exact href hashes as the tab you want to activate, then do some magic jQuery ...

```
    function opentab() {
            var draweritem = this;
            var target = $(draweritem).attr('href');
            $('.mdl-layout__obfuscator').click();
            $('a[href='+target+'].mdl-layout__tab span').click();
            return false;
    }
    $(".mdl-layout__drawer a").on('click',opentab);
```

This grabs the drawer item you just clicked on, reads the *href* it's pointing to, then clicks the "obfuscator" to close the drawer and then finds the layout tab based on that *href*.  It then clicks on the *span* inside the link (yeah, not the link itself).

Works for me!